# Newly added Activity designated as Main is not always "Main" Activity shown

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Allow me to explain my predicament.

I have been building an app for a while now where it would immediately enter my `MainActivity.class`. I had this Activity declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as such:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then I realized that I wanted to add a Login Activity to my app so a `NewMainActivity.class` was required. I've been able to successfully implement this new Activity. And I changed the `<intent-filter>` of the old `MainActivity.class` to the following:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

However this is where my problem arises.

When I press the back key on the Login Page (`NewMainActivity.class`) it goes through the `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` methods. When I start the App again the Login Page (`NewMainActivity.class`) is not shown, the old `MainActivity.class` is shown instead.

Can anyone guess what I'm still missing/doing wrong? It seems to me like it should always start on the Login Page everytime now. Let me know if a code sample would help.

Comment: try changing `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` to `<action android:name="com.package.name.VIEW" />`

Answer (score 0):

Delete from your old MainActivity.class the intent-filter that you've defined:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Update:** I've understood your question incorrectly at first. The intent-filter I've proposed to delete does nothing except exporting your activity. This means that any application can call the activity of your MainActivity.class So, in any case it should be deleted.

Now about the login activity. As I understand your scenario is the following. When you start your application it at first starts login activity. Then you enter your credentials and the main activity is appeared if the login process has been successful.

Thus, you have two activities in the stack: login and your main class. When you then push home button and run your application once again it starts from the last activity in the stack i.e. Main activity.

Thus, the problem is not in your intent-filters. You should finish your activities. In this case you'll always start from the login activity.

Comment: Deleted this intent filter and now I get the following message from the OS as a Toast Message: `Application is not installed on your phone`

Comment: Now clean the project and try to reinstall the application.

Comment: Hey Yury, I stopped coding my app for a while so I forgot to come back to this thread. I actually found the issue was caused by the IDE (eclipse) I was using and the fact that I copy-pasted my workspace between my laptop and my PC. This seemed to have adversely affected my project when loading into eclipse. When I created a fresh new project and copy-pasted the text within my classes everything worked as expected. Thanks for your help and I apologize taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

If at first Yury's suggestion does not work, and you did something similar to what I did, which was copy and pasting your workspace between multiple computers and loading the project to eclipse each time, then simply start a new project and copy the actual text within all your classes to fresh new classes in the new project.